# two vertical photos side-by-side in WordPress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, gallery, photo

I'm trying to get two vertical photos side-by-side in my WordPress site. Now I do it by assigning specific class to each photo - it means I have to do it manually, uploading photos to ftp, etc. and it kills me that there is probably some simple solution to this...

So now I have classes:
`.photo` - for normal full width photo
`.photo_left` & `.photo_right` - for photos side by side
`._photo_left_v` & `.photo_right_h` (and vice versa) - for placing vertical photos next to horizontal

My CSS looks like this:

```
.photo_left, .photo_right {
width: 49.45%;
max-height: 663px;
}

.photo_left, .photo_left_v, .photo_left_h {
float:left;
}

.photo_right, .photo_right_v, .photo_right_h {
float:right;
}

.photo_left_v, .photo_right_v {
width:30.5%;
}

.photo_left_h, .photo_right_h {
width: 68.65%;
}
```

In HTML it looks like:

```
<img class="photo_left" src="site.com/gallery/001.jpg" />
<img class="photo_right" src="site.com/gallery/002.jpg" />
```

Yes, it works, it's simple. But when i have to manage galleries, and blog posts like this then it takes a ton of time and frustrates me :/

The question is: can I do it and how by uploading photos through WP and addressing width property in CSS? Can I address it at all?

Answer (score 0):

the best and simple way it to use a flex box approach like

**HTML**

```
<div class='images_container'>
    <img class="photo_left" src="site.com/gallery/001.jpg" />
    <img class="photo_right" src="site.com/gallery/002.jpg" />
</div>
```

**css**

```
 .images_container{
   display:flex;
   justify-content:center;
   align-elment:center;
 }
.images_container img{
   width:50%;
 }
```

[JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/o0q0drrc/)